# CSS Issue with border

Tags: css, border

New to the site and fairly new to coding as a whole, but wanting to learn as well.

Basically what im trying to do is essentially make this border grey where the grey box is, and blue for the rest of it. I've tried googling it but struggling to find something that describes exactly what im looking for.

The grey area is 200px wide and starts roughly 26px in from the left side of the page.

Can anyone help at all? Thanks in advance

[Border Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeVig.png)

Header code is here - the grey box is part of a logo image.

```
 <div class="fusion-header" style="height: 91px; overflow: visible;">
        <div class="fusion-row">

    <div class="fusion-logo" data-margin-top="5px" data-margin-bottom="0px" data-margin-left="0px" data-margin-right="0px">
```

Comment: We can not help you without the code

Comment: I don't generally ask for code but for this question it would be better if you show us how the grey boxes are created. The answers could vary hugely depending on whether they are different elements or part of the same element etc.

Comment: Not sure if ive added the correct piece of code you require, but this was also in the css which links to it -     .fusion-header-v2 .fusion-header {
border-bottom-width: 4px; !important;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override a parent border in the logo element, by using a negative bottom margin with the size of the border.

```css
.header {
  background: #515151;
  border: 5px solid #5EDBE7;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #5D5D5D;
  
  /* Override the container vorder */
  border-bottom: 5px solid #999;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```